# Differences between two columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I have such Excel data:

[image]

I want to find records in ColumnA which do not exist in ColumnB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Two Columns With Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399060/excel-two-columns-with-duplicates)

Comment: @pnuts you're right; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393524/excel-delete-row-if-column-contains-value-from-to-remove-list may be closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in Row1 please try:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0),"#")
```

in Row1 and copy down to suit. `#` indicates the corresponding row's ColumnA value is not found in ColumnB. A number indicates the row in ColumnB that matches the ColumnA value for the row the value appears in.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that values starts from second row (A2 and B2)

Put below code in column where you want to display result

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A2),A2,"") //"" or 0 - whatever you want to put if B is not in A
```

Comment: Yes, thank you - it depends on locale. Polish Excel uses `;` marks.

Comment: In Polish excel if you try to write a formula with `,` instead od `;` it won't be valid. Thats because excel treat `,` as `.` separator.

But you're of course right with `COUNTIF`